# background or Image resizing and displaying in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a problem .. The background that I choose does not appear properly like what I want .. I tried some methods, but it did not work .. I hope to help me and thank you everyone

```
 private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(null);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\SMAHI\\Desktop\\Sans titre-1.jpg")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(0, -6, 3000, 2010);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 3000, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 2000, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

The picture appears like this and I don't want that

[image]

I want it to look roughly like this (I modified it with Photoshop, not code)

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of your code. Post the actual code.

Comment: If you want to use a JLabel, then you can use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will automatically resize to fill the space available. If you want it as a background on a panel you can do custom painting to dynamically resize the image. See [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a class that gives different options for displaying the image.